# Minimize,close and start menu button vanishing

Tags: windows-8.1

Once logging after a while my pull down close and minimize buttons on the top right and my start menu button in the bottom left, dont appear when my mouse hovers over where they should be. After i log off and on they come back but still vanish sometimes.

Comment: This link may help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/312589

Comment: No sorry, It is completely gone on everything (i mainly mean when out of desktop mode).